# How to add function for onChange when sometimes i dont have props?

Tags: reactjs, onchange

I use component for input. Sometimes i need two functions for onChange so in component use two , but sometimes i don't use props.change so i have an error.

This is my compoent

```
<input 
    type={this.props.type}
    name={this.props.id}
    onClick={this.props.clicked}
    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
    className={"form-control"}
    id={this.props.id}
    onChange={(e) => {
        this.handleChange(e);
        this.props.Change(e);
    }}
    disabled={this.props.disabled ===  true ? true : false}
    required={this.props.required ===  true ? true : false}
/>
```

if i don't send props in props.change i have an error

```
<TextBox
    type="text"
    label="ECode"
    placeholder="ECode"
    id="ECode"
    ref="ECode"
    error={this.state.ECodeError}
    value={this.state.ECode}
    disabled={false}
    required={true}
/>
```

Comment: try to call the `this.props.Change(e)` function inside the `this.handleChange(e)` function.

Answer (score 1):

While running change function from `onChange` event in child, check if the function is supplied

```
onChange={(e) => {
        this.handleChange(e);
        this.props.Change && this.props.Change(e);
}}
```

Additionally its better to have this login in handleChange itself since you will be able to avoid the inline arrow functions

```
handleChange = (e) => {
     // handleChange action here
     this.props.Change && this.props.Change(e);
}

onChange={this.handleChange}
```

Comment: Added an answer